# Criando um CRAWLER php

Tags: php, imagem, web-crawler

Sou leigo no assunto e gostaria de saber onde encontro mais informações sobre a criação de um crawler para baixar dados e imagens de alguns sites. Procurei bastante mas até agora não encontrei nada muito detalhado!

Agradeço as respostas

Answer (score 1):

### É necessário php?

Então, primeiramente é necessário entender a sua necessidade para ver se realmente precisamos fazer o uso de php nesse caso, uma vez que um crawler trabalha em cima de requisições por cliente. Existe um crawler que funciona como extensão muito bem para o Google Chrome, que se chama Web Scraper. [Você pode encontrá-lo aqui](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn)

### Vou utilizar um processo automatizado que buscará imagens periodicamente.

Nesse caso, se faz necessário o uso de php ou alguma linguagem de programação do lado de servidor. Nesse caso eu recomendo o framework PHPCrawl, [que pode ser encontrado aqui](http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html). Ele tem um funcionamento simples porém bem rico, com diversas opções. Se você dominar a linguagem php, apenas lendo o exemplo conseguirá entender o seu uso.

### O que eu preciso saber para fazer crawler?

O que eu recomendo fortemente é que você tenha um bom conhecimento em [Regexp](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), uma vez que precisará reconhecer padrões para fazer buscas precisas sobre o conteúdo que procura no site em que você está fazendo o crawling.

Comment: Usar Regex para buscas em páginas HTML costuma ser uma péssima ideia e só trazer frustração. O recomendado é usar XPATH ou CSS selectors para localizar e extrair dados e regex apenas para modifica-los.